# Apparent power vs. true power reading

Tags: power

If an electrician uses a ammeter and voltmeter to get readings, then multiplies the voltage reading and the amperage reading, is that true power or apparent power?

Comment: It depends on the load. Can you think what will be the case if the load is purely resistive, or purely reactive?

Comment: if you measure the current and voltage across an unknown load, that gives you the power the load is drawing, without any further knowledge, so it "appears" you have this amount of power, however you have reactive power because of reactive components which forms part of this apparent power, and the difference from that is the real/true power.

Comment: Volts * Amps is always apparent power. Sometimes, if the power factor is 1.0, then apparent power and true or real power are equal. But a hand held multi meter won't tell you the power factor so all you get is the apparent power.

Answer (score 6):

If current and voltage are measured using a simple voltmeter and ammeter, then you have no information about the phase relationship between the two. Therefore, it cannot be known if any power that is being delivered to the load gets returned to the source, and all you can infer from this limited data is "*apparent power*".

In the circuit below, an alternating voltage (240V RMS) is applied simultaneously across a resistive load Z1, and a capacitive load Z2, and the current through each is measured:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo1oSW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]
[image]

A simple RMS voltmeter and RMS ammeter would show only the values indicated by the green markers, namely 240V and 2.4A. The best you can do with this limited information is derive *apparent* power:

$$ P_{APPARENT} = V_{RMS} \times I_{RMS} = 240V \times 2.4A = 580W $$

This value also happens to be *true power* for the resistive load, because no energy is stored or returned to the source by the resistor; rather it is all dissipated immediately as heat. By that argument, you can say that the meters are actually telling you true power, but only for cases where the load is known to be purely resistive.

By contrast, the current through Z2 (the capacitor) is clearly 90° out of phase with voltage across it, meaning that all energy delivered to charge the capacitor is eventually returned to the source during discharge. Consequently, the total energy delivered to and kept by the capacitor over an entire cycle, is zero. In the long term, then, average power dissipated in Z2 is:

$$ P_{TRUE} = 0W $$

If there is any phase difference between load voltage and current, which would occur for a load with any amount of reactance, the voltage and current readings of RMS meters cannot be used as an indication of true power.

Answer (score 5):

> If an electrician uses a ammeter and voltmeter to get readings, then multiplies the voltage reading and the amperage reading, is that true power or apparent power?

Apparent power.

Comment: This. Because what the question describes is *the definition of* apparent power.

Answer (score 0):

Ammeters and voltmeters always indicate apparent values, by definition of "apparent." If the voltage and current are sinusoids the apparent values of current and voltage will also be true values. Multiplying apparent voltage and current by one another will give an apparent power with a different understanding of what "apparent" means. It might not be the same value that a hypothetical true power meter mould show.  As all the other answers point out, phase difference matters.